# Not able to create a lambda function through AWS command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function through the AWS command.When I'm executing the below command Its gives me the `Unknown option` error.

**AWS Command:**

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name function_name ukmon-appd-disabled- 
health-rules --runtime python3.7 --zip-file 
fileb://bin/disabled_health_rules.zip --handler index.handler --timeout 10 - 
-memory-size 1024 --role arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/crossaccount
```

**Error:**

```
Unknown options: ukmon-appd-disabled-health-rules
```

I've tried with different names.I am not able to understand what does that error mean. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `function_name`. It is being recognized as the value to the parameter `--function-name` instead of the `ukmon-appd-disabled-health-rules`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the argument `function-name` written twice.  Just remove one like this

```sh
aws lambda create-function --function-name ukmon-appd-disabled- 
health-rules --runtime python3.7 --zip-file 
fileb://bin/disabled_health_rules.zip --handler index.handler --timeout 10 - 
-memory-size 1024 --role arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/crossaccount
```